# How to download a library dependence on gradle for external use?

Tags: cordova, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, cordova-plugins

I have a project on PhoneGap and I am trying to build a plugin to use a FilePicker library. So, I build one Android Studio Project and I have it working. So, right now, that I know that I know how to do it, I just need to know how to reference the project on PhoneGap.

The problem is that I don't know where the project is downloaded when I use gradle for referencing it. I use:

```
compile 'io.filepicker:filepicker-android:3.8.13'
```

I just need to know where is this project folder, so I can copy and referencing it from phoneGap. Or how can I download it directly from gradle.

Comment: You mean that you don't know where the io.filepicker dependency is downloaded? So you seek the way to copy the downloaded jar, yes?

Comment: Yeah, but the thing is  io.filepicker is a project that works as a android-library. So its not only the .jar the io.filepicker has its owns references/classes/libraries/etc.... I cant find the whole project inside my app folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is an `aar` file. You can copy this file to *lib* folder with the following script:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
   mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
   compile 'io.filepicker:filepicker-android:3.8.14@aar'
}

task copyLibs(type: Copy) {
   from configurations.compile
   into 'lib'
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, I am new at gradle. I am not sure how to do this. Should I edit my build.gradle and put those things in? Or should I create a new file ? How can I run this script?

Comment: do you think it will work even if filepicker reference a third library? Because this is the case here...

Comment: It will download the aar file. Why wouldn't it work?

Comment: I dont know. nothing appears on the lib folder

Comment: I edited my build.gradle and then executed by the android studio

Comment: You executed what? You should run `copyLibs` task with `gradle copyLibs`.

Comment: Oh, I forget to add the task on the command. Sorry, and thanks